# Communication between php and (exe) C++ Console Application

Tags: php, c++, exec, console-application

*Is it possible to call an exe file and get result from it?*

(basic) For example if I have something like :

app.exe

```
#include <iostream>

void main() 
{
  std::cout << "<?php echo text_from_exe; ?>" << std::endl;
}
```

Can I call the exe like this :

```
<?php
  exec("app.exe");
?>
```

**And get the output like "`text_from_exe`" ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #include <iostream>

void main() 
{
  std::cout << "echo text_from_exe;" << std::endl;
}


<?php
  exec("app.exe", $output);
  eval(implode("\n",$output));
?>
```

Note: This is very dangerous and shouldn't really ever be run on a public-facing server

Comment: Thanks for the note. I can't run it, because the page is like in an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the list of [program execution functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php) available in PHP. The [`shell_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function in particular can return a console program's output in a PHP variable.

Comment: I tried the shell_exec function but my page won't finish loading, it is like in an infinite loop :|

Comment: Use `passthru` function and see if displays anything (passthru sends content returned by the program directly to the browser instead of returning as a variable).